# What is printing this number after my python script executes

Tags: python, linux, darwin

Please forgive me for asking a simple question of python.  This is my first time using python.

I'm writing this script on a mac book pro for now.  It will probably be deployed on a Centos server later.  The script grabs gets file as an argument.  I'll deal with processing the output later.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   print ("Not enough arguments")
   print ("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " log_file output_file")
   print ("i.e. " + sys.argv[0] + " stream.log output.csv")
   sys.exit(1)
else:
   input = open (sys.argv[1])
   output = open (sys.argv[2],'w')

proc = subprocess.Popen("cat " + input.name + " | cut -d ',' -f 3 | sort | uniq | wc -l", shell=True)

print "got here"
output.close()
print "got here22222"
input.close()
```

I just ran it from a terminal and it executes.  However, after it prints out the last

got here22222

there's a delay of a couple seconds and then it prints out 567.  However, there's no print 567 in my script above.  Does anyone know why it's printing this number?  How do I stop it from printing this number?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

```
./test.py a b
got here
got here22222
~/test$      567
```

Comment: I think it's coming from the subprocess call to `cat`. You're cat-ing (in a pipeline) a file, and 567 is likely the result of that pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final stage of your pipeline is `wc -l` which is probably generating the number `567`.  It takes a few seconds to reach that point.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thank you. It was the wc -l.  I also figured out how to assign the output to to a variable.  I need to put a stdout=subprocess.PIPE; e.g. the new python cmd should be  proc = subprocess.Popen("cat " + input.name + " | cut -d ',' -f 3 | sort | uniq | wc -l", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Answer (score 2):

to stop this from happening you can wait for the subprocess using [`proc.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) otherwise I guess the output of the piped commands is 567